# Menubars etc individually scaled for different apps in Win 11

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-surface-pro

I recently bought a Surface Pro 8 with Win 11 and I am experiencing something very odd and annoying: The menubars and everything else seems to be scaled differently for every program. Specifically for browsers, while Edge has the bars sized "normally", Chrome has them blown up by something like 150%. Interestingly, Brave and Firefox also are different. All in all, no two browsers displays the menu bars in the same hight.

I tried everything (I assume), from UI scaling to browser scaling settings. Nothing worked. I even went so far to erase the disk and reinstall Windows new - only to arrive at the same problem out-of-the-box (see image):

[image]

Now, obviously, how can I make sure that all programs have their menubars in the same height - as with all other programs and windows versions before?

Comment: Edge is in Fullscreen mode. If you change Chrome and Brave to Fullscreen, the menubar will have the same height,..

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't. Also, Chrome and Brave are displaying different heights in non-fullscreen modes

Comment: how can I make sure that all programs have their menubars in the same height -   .........  It is app dependent on my Windows 11 machines.  Edge, Office, Adobe all have different menubar heights. Is this a necessary feature for you?

Comment: I have gone back to a Windows 10 VM.  Menubar height is a function of the App you are using (including Edge and Chrome on Windows 10) and so I do not think you can do what you are trying to do.